# How to reduce memory usage when returning a file over a stream with WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, wcf

I have 1 large and many small files being sent to a server each day. The server parses and creates/recreates/updates a sqlite DB when it receives these. The client machines also need this DB, and can request it or request updates. Everything is connected via LAN.

The client machines need the DB as they do not have reliable internet access so using a cloud DB is not an option. The server may also be down so asking the server for single queries is not reliable.

The large file update touches every single row in the DB since it's possible some information was missed in the deltas. As a result we can not send the large delta to the clients and I believe makes more sense to just recreate them on the client.

Since the client machines are poor, querying the server for rows and making large deltas on those machines is very time intensive and can take 2+ hours. Since this occurs daily, having 2 out of 24 hours of stale data is not an option.

We decided on having the clients request the entire db, when this happens the server compresses and sends the db, which only takes a few minutes.

To do this I've set up the server to compress the db, and then return a `MemoryStream`.

```
var dbCopyPath = ".\\db_copy.db";

using (var readFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    Log("Compressing db copy...");
    using (var writeFileStream = new FileStream(dbCopyPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
    {
        using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(writeFileStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
        {
            readFileStream.CopyTo(gzipStream);
        }
    }
}

return new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(dbCopyPath));
```

I've tried some other methods like writing a `FileStream` to a `GZipStream(new MemoryStream())` and returning the `GZipStream.ToArray()`, or just returning the memory stream straight from the file.

The issue with all the options I've tried is that they all reserve a large amount of memory (or just don't work). I've seen the process consistently reserve 600mb of memory when running this when I just have a 200mb file after compression. If the files that come in get too large this will eventually start giving me out of memory exceptions. On the client side, I'm able to just read the stream like this:

`var dbStream = client.OpenRead(downloadUrl);`

This makes it so the memory usage does not spike at all on the client when downloading the data.

My ideal solution would be a way to stream data directly from the file over the server to the client. I'm not sure if this possible since I've tried this with many different combinations of streams, but if there was some way to have a lazy stream like the server doesn't load portions of the stream until the client needs them for writing that would be ideal, though again I'm not sure if that's possible or even fully makes sense.

I tried my best to avoid the XY problem so if there's anything I missed please let me know, I appreciate any help with this. Thank you

Comment: This statement: `new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(dbCopyPath));` will allocate at least  2 times your compressed filesize: 1 time for the byte that comes out of ReadAllBytes and 1 time for the backing store inside MemoryStream. If you are planing on keeping the MemoryStream why don't you gzip directly to the memorystream? You can then copy the stream to disk if you need to and return that same instance to the caller.

Comment: @rene do you mean something like this https://snippet.host/awnm ? I have tried this a few different ways, if I use 3 `using` blocks, something weird happens where my endpoint gets called over and over even though my client does not make any requests (and the client does get the returned stream). If I don't use the `using` blocks like in my example, my DB corrupts when it's transferred (about 22kb goes missing). To remedy the corruption, I've tried flushing the streams but that did not work. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: You need a using on that GZipStream before you reset the Position on the memorry stream. That will write the final compressed block to the stream. You can't do a using for the MemoryStream because that will dispose it and make it useless for your caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know how you transfer your data (NetworkStream byte[], etc.), you could also return your compressed database directly as a FileStream and thus do without the MemoryStream:

```
private static Stream GetCompressedDbStream(string path)
{
  var tempFileStream = new TemporaryFileStream();

  try
  {
    using (var readFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
      using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(tempFileStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal, true))
      {
        readFileStream.CopyTo(gzipStream);
      }
    }

    tempFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return tempFileStream;
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    // Log to console or alert user.
    tempFileStream.Dispose();
    throw;
  }
}
```

In order to manage the scope of the temporary file correctly, I have my implementation of a class 'TemporaryFileStream' here. This will delete the temporary file as soon as the stream is disposed:

```
public class TemporaryFileStream : Stream, IDisposable
{

  private readonly FileStream _fileStream;
  private bool _disposedValue;

  public override bool CanRead => _fileStream.CanRead;

  public override bool CanSeek => _fileStream.CanSeek;

  public override bool CanWrite => _fileStream.CanWrite;

  public override long Length => _fileStream.Length;

  public override long Position
  {
    get => _fileStream.Position;
    set => _fileStream.Position = value;
  }

  public TemporaryFileStream()
  {
    _fileStream = new FileStream(Path.GetTempFileName(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    new FileInfo(_fileStream.Name).Attributes = FileAttributes.Temporary;
  }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (!_disposedValue)
    {
      if (disposing)
      {
        _fileStream.Dispose();
        File.Delete(_fileStream.Name);
      }

      _disposedValue = true;
    }
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    Dispose(disposing: true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  public override void Flush() => _fileStream.Flush();
  public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => _fileStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
  public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => _fileStream.Seek(offset, origin);
  public override void SetLength(long value) => _fileStream.SetLength(value);
  public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => _fileStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);

}
```

You can then use a simple CopyTo or Read in order to transfer the data efficiently:

```
using var stream = GetCompressedDbStream(@"DbPath");
// CopyTo ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it has reduced the memory usage from 600mb to 400mb for my test. One thing I noticed is that the stream seems to never dispose since the file does not delete. From my endpoint I basically only have `return GetCompressedDbStream(dbPath)` . Do you know how I could get the stream to dispose?

Comment: Gernerally you can dispose objects with the Dispose() method (if available). In my example I used the **using** statement which calls internally this method for you. Ensure to use either Dispose() or the using statement.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. For context, I'm using your code verbatim for testing. If I have `using (var stream = GetCompressedDbStream(@"DbPath")){ stream.copyTo(returnStream)}` I can `return returnStream` from inside the `using` or outside. If I return within the `using`, the server is not able to dispose the stream, and the endpoint appears to get hit repeatedly even though only 1 call was made, while the client never seems to receive a response. From outside, I'm unable to return a closed stream. Is there a way to dispose on the server after I've returned?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, only use the `using` statement on the topmost call - so when you return a stream from a function, don't use` using` on that stream until you are in the outermost call. But why exactly are you returning a stream at all when you've already written that data to it with CopyTo()?

Comment: Since the DB is created on the server I need to get it to the client machines. If I understand properly, I should return the stream from an endpoint, and then run `using` on it from the client. To do that I return the stream from `/db` which has `return GetCompressedDbStream(dbPath)`, and then on the client I am reading it with this code https://snippet.host/eoud . This writes the DB properly to the client. I'm guessing what's happening is the stream disposes on the client, so the file is never deleted on the server. Do you think that's what's happening or am I off base? Thanks again

Comment: Never return a stream from an endpoint. This completely destroys the benefits of a stream because the data on the stream must be entirely present. Please try instead writing data directly onto the response stream. Depending on what technology are you using (assuming ASP), you could do that like so: `stream.CopyTo(Body)` in your endpoint method.

Comment: We're using WCF, I updated the question to reflect this. After some looking it seems difficult to not have to load the stream into memory for a WCF response. So I think I will either have to figure out a way to get the full benefits of a stream using WCF or see if we can switch to ASP for this. Thanks for the help with this. Since your answer did reduce the memory of my current solution I will mark it as correct